# Create Unsubscribe Link in Laravel email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm trying to allow a user to Unsubscribe from a email link via the server side.

Simply want them to click the link, add a column to my table and show them a page that tells them they have been unsubscribed.

The link looks like this:

```
https://mysite.test/unsubscribe-confirm/eyJpdiI6Ims3Y3RJdHhvWTgyNGVLais1UXlzdlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUUF0NFZUUkNqTklmTTExTVRmZEdyaEUvN1kzcXpLNmNhRit3enpPNDE0ak5xalRaa1JQQS91elBCazIzTWFxayIsIm1hYyI6IjMzZDM4MDUwNTYzZjY1ZjQ4OTEyNDI3ZjJhY2M4NzgxNzgwMDFiMGQ2NjQ0ZjFiMGFjNGJlNjg3YzY0Zjc5NTkiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==/1
```

In my job `JobToSendEmails` I'm creating the `$unsubscribeLink` like this:

```
// Generate token
$unsubscribeToken = encrypt($sponsor->email);
// Generate unsubscribe link
$unsubscribeLink = route('unsubscribe.confirm', ['token' => $unsubscribeToken, 'campaign_id' => $emailCampaign->id]);
```

And then passing to my email like this:

```
Mail::to($sponsor->email)->send(new EmailToUsers(
...
$unsubscribeLink
));
```

Then in the `EmailToUsers` view I have this line:

```
If you no longer wish to receive these emails, you can [unsubscribe]({{ $unsubscribeLink }}) at any time.
```

The link goes to this route:

```
Route::post('/unsubscribe-confirm/{token}/{campaign_id}', [EmailPreferenceController::class, 'confirmUnsubscribe'])->name('unsubscribe.confirm');
```

Then in the EmailPreferenceController the `confirmUnsubscribe` method looks like this:

```
    public function confirmUnsubscribe()
    {
        $token = Request::get('token');
        $user  = User::findByToken($token);
        if ($user) {
            $emailCampaignId         = Request::get('email_campaign_id');
            $emailCampaignPreference = EmailCampaignPreference::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'user_id'           => $user->id,
                    'email_campaign_id' => $emailCampaignId,
                ],
                [
                    'opt_out' => true,
                    'email'   => $user->email,
                ]
            );

            return redirect()->route('unsubscribe');
        }
        Log::error('User not found by token: ' . $token);

        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
```

`findByToken` looks like this:

```
public static function findByToken($token): User
  {
    $email = decrypt($token);
    return static::where('email', $email)->first();
  }
```

When I click the unsubscribe link in the email, I get the error:

> Symfony \Component \HttpKernel \Exception \MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> "The GET method is not supported for route
> unsubscribe-confirm/eyJpdiI6Ims3Y3RJdHhvWTgyNGVLais1UXlzdlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUUF0NFZUUkNqTklmTTExTVRmZEdyaEUvN1kzcXpLNmNhRit3enpPNDE0ak5xalRaa1JQQS91elBCazIzTWFxayIsIm1hYyI6IjMzZDM4MDUwNTYzZjY1ZjQ4OTEyNDI3ZjJhY2M4NzgxNzgwMDFiMGQ2NjQ0ZjFiMGFjNGJlNjg3YzY0Zjc5NTkiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==/1.
> Supported methods: POST."

What can I do to fix this? I'm using a Post method on the route. I would like to keep this format in the email, `[unsubscribe]({{ $unsubscribeLink }})`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you're clicking the link in your email, it will perform a get request, this error came from that.

You can try to change the route from post to get or add a form inside your email wich will make a post request.

Comment: I tried adding a form in the email, but it kept trying to open in the client and received a 419 error. I will try coming back to that though.

Comment: Don't forget to add @csrf inside your form, this is why you get error 419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the route from post to get was the main issue.

```
Changed:
Route::post('/unsubscribe-confirm/{token}/{campaign_id}', [EmailPreferenceController::class, 'confirmUnsubscribe'])->name('unsubscribe.confirm');

To:
Route::get('/unsubscribe-confirm/{token}/{campaign_id}', [EmailPreferenceController::class, 'confirmUnsubscribe'])->name('unsubscribe.confirm');
```

Then in the EmailPreferenceController the confirmUnsubscribe method now looks like this:

```
    public function confirmUnsubscribe($token, $campaign_id)
    {
        $user = User::findByToken($token);

        if ($user) {
            $emailCampaignPreference = EmailCampaignPreference::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'user_id'           => $user->id,
                    'email_campaign_id' => $campaign_id,
                    'opt_out'           => true,
                    'email'             => $user->email,
                ]
            );

            return redirect()->route('unsubscribe');
        }
        Log::error('User not found by token: ' . $token);

        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
```

User Model `findByToken` looks like this:

```
    public static function findByToken($token): User
    {
        $email = decrypt($token);
        return static::where('email', $email)->first();
    }
```

User gets unsubscribed immediately and data gets stored in table.